# Test Google Cloud PubSub emulator with a push subscription

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-console, google-cloud-pubsub-emulator

I'm trying to setup a GCP PubSub service that will work with a push type subscription. However it's impossible to create one in the developement stage, while I have no accessible endpoints.

I assumed that the [emulator](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/emulator) would allow me to specify a local endpoint so that the service would run flawlessly in local.

However, after setting it up, I couldn't find a way in the [Node.js pubsub library](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub) to create a subscription while specifying its options, there is no example for this.

This is the pretty simple way to create a simple, default, pull, subscription:

```
await pubsub.topic(topicName).createSubscription(subscriptionName);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an [example](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/blob/master/samples/subscriptions.js#L135-L160) of how you would set up push subscription. It is the same as how you would set it up if you were running in the actual Pub/Sub environment. Specify ‘pushEndpoint’ as your local endpoint. When running on the emulator, it will not require authentication for your endpoint.

You can do something like the following:

```
 // Imports the Google Cloud client library
 const {PubSub} = require('@google-cloud/pubsub');

 // Creates a client
 const pubsub = new PubSub();

 const options = {
   pushConfig: {
     // Set to your local endpoint.
     pushEndpoint: `your-local-endpoint`,
   },
 };

 await pubsub.topic(topicName).createSubscription(subscriptionName, options);
```

Comment: It works with local endpoints! thank you, I missed the example

Comment: Has this actually been verified to work correctly? How do you host "your-local-endpoint" to work around the fact that functions-framework is apparently broken when it comes to hosting PubSub event handlers.https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs/issues/41

Answer (score 0):

You should have an environment variable named "PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST" that points the the emulator host.

my local pubsub emulator have the following url - http://pubsub:8085 so i am adding the following env variable to the service that connects it:

```
export PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST=http://pubsub:8085
```

The following code should work:

```
const projectId="your-project-id";

 // Creates a client. It will recognize the env variable automatically
const pubsub = new PubSub({
  projectId
});

pubsub.topic(topicName).createSubscription(subscriptionName);
```